# Flutter Collapsible Appbar with custom layout and animation

Tags: flutter, user-interface, animation, flutter-layout, user-experience

I am trying to create an app bar that looks like the following image when expanded

[image]

When collapsing I only need the initial column of text to be available in the app bar, so the image should fade away and the text column to animate and become the Appbar title

I have tried using SliverAppBar with a custom scroll view but the Flexible space's title is not looking good also I don't know how to make the image disappear alone and show only the text when collapsed.

As of now, this is the expanded state

[image]

And when I try to collapse it, this happens

[image]

Here's the code for the same

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Get.back(),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                          text: "Buffet Deal\n",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Flash Deal",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (_model.imgUrl != null)
                    CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: _model.imgUrl!,
                    ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 18,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          expandedHeight: Get.height * 0.2,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFF4F4)),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container()
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include what you’ve tried so far? And what is the state on collapse mode.

Comment: Hi, @YeasinSheikh I have added the solution and images I have tried. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the SliverAppBar's flexible space image disappear whenever the expanded space collapse just use the [`FlexibleSpaceBar.background`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar/background.html) property.

To solve the overlapping text just wrap the `FlexibleSpaceBar` around a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get if it's expanded or not and adjust the text positioning.

Check out the result below (Also, the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=31f558c9d6be34cd156a6ad72e136155)):

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final expandedHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2;
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            leading: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => {},
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              final fraction =
                  max(0, constraints.biggest.height - kToolbarHeight) /
                      (expandedHeight - kToolbarHeight);
              return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24 * (1 - fraction)),
                          child: const Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                                text: "Buffet Deal\n",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Flash Deal",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 18)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                background: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Image.network(
                    "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x225?sig=1&licors",
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFF4F4),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 1000))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That solves the image problem, how to overcome the overlapping of text column and the back arrow?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the solution for this also... check it out.