# how can I achieve these effects in design (snap effect, change align when scrolling)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I need to design screen like this in short video[video_link](https://youtube.com/shorts/DFdV_KKDqBk?feature=share)

I did this but its not very similar to the previous effect

here I create `CustomScrollView` with `NotificationListener` to achieve snap effect, but is still begging and isused TransitionAppBar to make appbar and used SliverPersistentHeader which implements SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate to control on align size and position

```
 import 'dart:math';
 import 'dart:developer' as d;
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
 
 class FinalScroll extends StatefulWidget {
   FinalScroll({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   State<FinalScroll> createState() => _FinalScrollState();
 }
 
 class _FinalScrollState extends State<FinalScroll> {
   final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
 
   final double kLength = 300;
 
   final double kLengthSnap = 225;
 
   final Duration kDurationSnap = const Duration(milliseconds: 20);
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if (!(!_controller.hasClients || _controller.offset == 0)) {
       // print('controll offset ${_controller.offset}');
 
     }
     double sizeImage = kLength;
     return SafeArea(
       child: Scaffold(
         body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, s) {
           return NotificationListener(
             onNotification: (scrollEndNotification) {
               // print('controll offset ${_controller.offset}');
 
               if (scrollEndNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                 if (_controller.offset < 0.4 * kLength) {
                   print('snap from CTB');
 
                   Future.microtask(
                     () {
                       return _controller.animateTo(0.0,
                           duration: kDurationSnap, curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                     },
                   );
                   setState(() {
                     sizeImage = kLength;
                   });
                 }
                 if (_controller.offset > kLength * 0.4 &&
                     _controller.offset <= kLength * .6) {
                   print('snap from CTT');
 
                   Future.microtask(() => _controller.animateTo(kLength * 0.6,
                       duration: kDurationSnap, curve: Curves.bounceInOut));
                   setState(() {
                     sizeImage = 50;
                   });
                 }
               }
 
               return false;
             },
             child: CustomScrollView(
               controller: _controller,
               physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
               slivers: <Widget>[
                 TransitionAppBar(
                   extent: kLength,
                   sizeImage: sizeImage,
                   avatar: const Text("Rancho"),
                   title: const Text(''),
                 ),
                 SliverList(
                   delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                     (context, index) {
                       return ListTile(
                         title: Text("${index}a"),
                       );
                     },
                     childCount: 25,
                   ),
                 )
               ],
             ),
           );
         }),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
 
 class TransitionAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
   final Widget avatar;
   final Widget title;
   final double extent;
   final double sizeImage;
 
   const TransitionAppBar({
     required this.avatar,
     required this.title,
     this.extent = 250,
     required this.sizeImage,
     Key? key,
   }) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   State<TransitionAppBar> createState() => _TransitionAppBarState();
 }
 
 class _TransitionAppBarState extends State<TransitionAppBar>
     with TickerProviderStateMixin {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MediaQuery.removePadding(
       context: context,
       removeBottom: true,
       child: SliverPersistentHeader(
         pinned: true,
         floating: true,
         delegate: _TransitionAppBarDelegate(
             avatar: widget.avatar,
             sizeImage: widget.sizeImage,
             title: widget.title,
             extent: widget.extent > 200 ? widget.extent : 200,
             vsync: this),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
 
 class _TransitionAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
   _TransitionAppBarDelegate(
       {required this.avatar,
       required this.title,
       required this.sizeImage,
       this.extent = 250,
       required this.vsync});
 
   final double sizeImage;
 
   final Widget avatar;
   final Widget title;
   final double extent;
 
   ///   ===================  init  ========= ////
   final _avatarMarginTween =
       EdgeInsetsTween(begin: EdgeInsets.zero, end: const EdgeInsets.all(16));
 
   ///from BTC
   final _titleMarginTweenBTC = EdgeInsetsTween(
       begin: EdgeInsets.zero, end: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70));
   final _titleAlignTweenBTC = AlignmentTween(
       begin: const Alignment(-.7, .8), end: const Alignment(-1.0, 0.2));
   final _avatarAlignTweenBTC =
       AlignmentTween(begin: const Alignment(-1, 1), end: Alignment.centerLeft);
 
   ///from CTT
   final _titleMarginTweenCTT = EdgeInsetsTween(
       begin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70), end: EdgeInsets.zero);
   final _titleAlignTweenCTT = AlignmentTween(
       begin: const Alignment(-1.0, 0.2), end: const Alignment(-.2, 0));
   final _avatarAlignTweenCTT = AlignmentTween(
       begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: const Alignment(-.7, 0.0));
 
   final decorationTween = DecorationTween(
       begin: const BoxDecoration(
           shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
           color: Colors.red,
           image: DecorationImage(
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
               alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
               image: AssetImage('asset/dash.jpeg'))),
       end: const BoxDecoration(
         shape: BoxShape.circle,
         color: Colors.yellow,
         image: DecorationImage(
           alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
           fit: BoxFit.fill,
           image: AssetImage(
             'asset/dash.jpeg',
           ),
         ),
       ));
 
   @override
   Widget build(
       BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
     final double topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
 
     final double visibleMainHeight = maxExtent - shrinkOffset - topPadding;
     final double extraToolbarHeight =
         max(minExtent - extent - topPadding - (kToolbarHeight), 0.0);
     final double visibleToolbarHeight =
         visibleMainHeight - extent - extraToolbarHeight;
 
     final bool isScrolledUnder =
         overlapsContent || (shrinkOffset > maxExtent - minExtent);
     final double toolbarOpacity =
         (visibleToolbarHeight / (kToolbarHeight)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
 
     final progress = min(1.0, shrinkOffset / maxExtent);
     //margin
     final avatarMargin = _avatarMarginTween.lerp(progress);
     final titleMarginBTC = _titleMarginTweenBTC.lerp(progress);
     final titleMarginCTT = _titleMarginTweenCTT.lerp(shrinkOffset / 300);
     //align
     final avatarAlignBTC = _avatarAlignTweenBTC.lerp(progress);
     final titleAlignBTC = _titleAlignTweenBTC.lerp(progress);
     final avatarAlignCTT = _avatarAlignTweenCTT.lerp(shrinkOffset / extent);
     final titleAlignCTT = _titleAlignTweenCTT.lerp(shrinkOffset / extent);
     //decoration
     final decorationT = decorationTween.lerp(progress);
     // print(
     //     'shrinkOffset:$shrinkOffset maxExtent: $maxExtent   minExtent:  $minExtent  progress : $progress');
 print(sizeImage);
     final Widget toolbar = Stack(
       fit: StackFit.passthrough,
       children: <Widget>[
         AnimatedContainer(
           duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
           height: minExtent,
           constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: minExtent),
           color: Colors.grey.shade100,
         ),
         LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
           var checkIfProgressThanFromValue = progress < 0.3;
           var checkLessThan1 = !(progress > 0.01);
           return SizedBox(
             height: sizeImage,
             width: sizeImage==maxExtent?MediaQuery.of(context).size.width:30,
             child: Row(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
               children: [
                 Flexible(
                   child: Padding(
                     padding: avatarMargin,
                     child: AnimatedContainer(
                       duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                       constraints: BoxConstraints(
                           maxHeight: maxExtent,
                           maxWidth: constraint.maxWidth,
                           minHeight: 0,
                           minWidth: 0),
                       height: checkLessThan1 ? maxExtent : 50,
                       width: checkLessThan1
                           ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                           : 30,
                       // decoration: decorationT,
                       child: OverflowBox(
                         maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                         child: SizedBox(
                           height: sizeImage,
                           width: checkLessThan1
                               ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                               : 30,
                           child: FittedBox(
                             fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                             alignment: shrinkOffset > minExtent
                                 ? avatarAlignCTT
                                 : avatarAlignBTC,
                             child: ClipRRect(
                               borderRadius: checkLessThan1
                                   ? BorderRadius.zero
                                   : BorderRadius.circular(
                                       min(24, progress * 24)),
                               clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                               child: AnimatedSize(
                                 duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                 child: Image.asset(
                                   'asset/dash.jpeg',
 
                                   // alignment: shrinkOffset > minExtent
                                   //     ? avatarAlignCTT
                                   //     : avatarAlignBTC,
                                   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                   height: sizeImage,
                                   width: sizeImage == maxExtent
                                       ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                                       : 30,
                                   // height: checkIfProgressThanFromValue
                                   //     ? maxExtent
                                   //     : 50,
                                   // width: checkIfProgressThanFromValue
                                   //     ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                                   //     : 50,
                                 ),
                               ),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           );
         }),
         _RenderTilte(
             progress: progress,
             titleMarginBTC: titleMarginBTC,
             titleMarginCTT: titleMarginCTT,
             titleAlignBTC: titleAlignBTC,
             titleAlignCTT: titleAlignCTT)
       ],
     );
 
     final Widget appBar = FlexibleSpaceBar.createSettings(
       minExtent: minExtent,
       maxExtent: maxExtent,
       currentExtent: max(minExtent, maxExtent - shrinkOffset),
       child: toolbar,
     );
     return SafeArea(
       child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, c) {
         return SizedBox(
             height: c.maxHeight,
             width: c.maxWidth,
             child: ClipRect(child: appBar));
       }),
     );
   }
 
   @override
   double get maxExtent => extent;
 
   @override
   double get minExtent => max(kToolbarHeight, (maxExtent * .33));
 
   @override
   bool shouldRebuild(_TransitionAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
     return true;
   }
 
   @override
   OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration get stretchConfiguration =>
       OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration(
           stretchTriggerOffset: 150, onStretchTrigger: () async {});
 
   @override
   FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration? get snapConfiguration =>
       FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration(
           curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
           duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
 
   @override
   PersistentHeaderShowOnScreenConfiguration? get showOnScreenConfiguration =>
       const PersistentHeaderShowOnScreenConfiguration();
 
   @override
   final TickerProvider vsync;
 }
 
 class _RenderTilte extends StatelessWidget {
   const _RenderTilte({
     Key? key,
     required this.progress,
     required this.titleMarginBTC,
     required this.titleMarginCTT,
     required this.titleAlignBTC,
     required this.titleAlignCTT,
   }) : super(key: key);
 
   final double progress;
   final EdgeInsets titleMarginBTC;
   final EdgeInsets titleMarginCTT;
   final Alignment titleAlignBTC;
   final Alignment titleAlignCTT;
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Padding(
       padding: progress < 0.3 ? titleMarginBTC : titleMarginCTT,
       child: Align(
         alignment: progress < 0.3 ? titleAlignBTC : titleAlignCTT,
         child: Opacity(
           opacity: progress == 0 || progress == 1 ? 1 : progress * 0.01,
           child: const Text(
             'abd alazeez ',
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

here how to build the previous design and I don't know what the next step

Comment: Try Sliverscroll or any sliver

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092277/flutter-collapsible-appbar-with-custom-layout-and-animation/73093528#73093528) answer your question? It'd need some adjustments but the logic is there.

Comment: @lepsch this is not similar .is very simple i need to  make that without using FlexibleSpaceBar it isn't given full control on my widget